# Ubuntu grub customization through terminal ?

Tags: grub2, 14.10

I was just wondering what would be the equivalent of bcdedit(windows) in Ubuntu as I am having some problems to resume system after hibernation in Ubuntu 14.10.

I am currently using boot-repair package, but that doesn't give you the manual control over grub(bios) state.

Answer (score 0):

This [community page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) has lots of details and links. What you need to know is to edit `/etc/default/grub` and files in `/etc/default/grub.d/` then run `update-grub` to make the changes live. I've not used boot-repair yet but it looks interesting though it's not part of a default Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Actually boot-repair posts data to the ubuntu.com clipboard by default? That would not be my first choice but I understand why they do it.